# Blocking vs Non blocking IO?

Tags: udp

I have just started network programming and I am a bit confused Does the read and write operations behavior {in regards to blocking or not} change depending if we have a regular file descritpor or a socket descriptor (UDP socket or TCP socket).

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about programming are off-topic here. Fortunately, there are many network-savvy programmers on [so], where you should try to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking I/O
*  here the calling system does not return control to the caller
until the operation finished.
*as for a result, the caller is blocked and
cannot perform other activities during that specified time.

Non-blocking Synchronous I/O

*here  call returns control to the caller immediately and the
caller  not made to wait.
* The invoked system immediately returns one
of two responses:
. If the call was executed and the results were ready,
then the caller is told of that. Alternatively, the invoked system can
tell the caller that the system has no resources (no data in the
socket) to perform the requested action.

- Non-blocking Asynchronous I/O
  *means that the calling function returns control to the caller
  immediately, reporting that the requested action was started. 
  *here
  invoked system will notify the caller (by callback for example), when
  the result is ready for processing.